# Global objects with Node.js + Express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm studying Node.js + Express, coding a basic login example. My `/login` route is set inside the **routes/login.js** file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connectionpool = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'user',
    password : 'pass',
    database : 'database'
});

router.post('/', function(req,res){ 
    connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('CONNECTION error: ',err);
            res.statusCode = 503;
              res.send({
                result: 'error',
                err:    err.code
            });
        } else {
            // Do something
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I was wondering: how can I make the **mysql** or the **connectionpool** visible in the entire application? I don't want to redeclare them on each route file I'll create. I'm looking something like an include or require method.

Any idea?

Comment: Put that in a separate Node.js module and require it in all the files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a separate module to act as an interface to retrieving SQL connections like so:

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connectionpool = mysql.createPool({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'user',
      password : 'pass',
      database : 'database'
    });

    exports.getConnection = function (callback) {
      connectionpool.getConnection(callback);
    };
```

Then in another file:

```
    var connections = require('./connections');

        connections.getConnection(function (err, c) { 
    // Use c as a connection 
     c.query("select * from table limit 10 ",function(err,rows){
    //this is important release part 
                c.release();
                if(!err) {
                    console.log(rows);
                }           
            });

});
```