# Single MySQL connection over multiple modules in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm going for NodeJS. Though, as usual, some problems occur.

I have few controllers in `/controllers` which I include in `/routes.js`;
I am using `node-mysql` as a database wrapper and I am really wondering if there is any better alternative to what I'm currently doing.

At the moment, in `routes.js`, I'm connecting to the database like the following:

```
pool            = require('mysql').createPool({ host: 'host', user: 'root', password: 'pass', database: 'db' })
```

Now, I would really like with mysql in my `User` controller as well, which is already required into the `routes` file.

I understand that I need to require and connect to mysql in `User` controller again, but is this a good practice ?

Is there any better alternative rather than requiring `node-mysql` and connecting to the DB in each controller ?

Am I missing anything here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For node-mysql, refer this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731214/node-mysql-connection-pooling),

OR You can use [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/), you can read [this article](https://milinaudara.wordpress.com/2014/05/24/an-introduction-to-sequelize-js/) to know advantages of Sequelize.

For your requirement,

If you are going to use Sequelize,
Configure connection pool and import sequelize model into your js file and directly you can query the db.

Comment: I don't think you understood correctly what I have asked. I know about the connection pooling, I am already doing it if you look at the code I pasted. I'm just wondering if requiring `node-mysql` again and again in each controller is a bad practice or not. And if it is, what's the better alternative.

Comment: require node-mysql again and again won't make difference but it's not right way to do it. But you can export `var pool = require('mysql').createPool(opts);` and use it.

Comment: Ok, so what I gathered is that for whatever bit of object I tend to initialize quite often, it's better to have it "initialized" already in a module and export it everywhere I need to use it. Makes sense to me. Thanks.